# Streaming API - Can retrieve new as well as OLD value?

Tags: api, streaming-api

i want to get not notified when there are any changes on a field...Im able to get the new value of the field but is it possible to get old(before update) and new(after update) value using streaming API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard API, once the records are updated, you can only get the new values. If you want to get the old and new values, you would need to use a trigger to trigger a Platform Event, or otherwise have had a copy of the data before it was updated.

Comment: Would be pretty cool to have the old value - I also ran into that a while back. Probably wouldn't be hard for sf to include it, given it's probably internally powered by some sort of trigger anyway.

Comment: once again thank you @sfdcfox